# Heroku: Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, flask, heroku, deployment

I have successfully deployed the ML application on Heroku platform. I am getting below error while click on predict button to predict the score:

```
BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

But it is working fine when I am running this app in local. What could be the reason that this error only comes while deploying it?

I am using python 3.7.9 and Flask library.

**App.py file:**

```
# Importing essential libraries
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle
import numpy as np

# Load the Random Forest CLassifier model
#filename = 'lasso_regressor_model.pkl'
model = pickle.load(open('ipl_score_prediction1.pkl', 'rb'))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def Home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def predict():
    temp_array = list()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        batting_team = request.form['batting-team']
        if batting_team == 'Chennai Super Kings':
            temp_array = temp_array + [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Delhi Daredevils':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Kings XI Punjab':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Kolkata Knight Riders':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Mumbai Indians':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Rajasthan Royals':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Royal Challengers Bangalore':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
        elif batting_team == 'Sunrisers Hyderabad':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

        bowling_team = request.form['bowling-team']
        if bowling_team == 'Chennai Super Kings':
            temp_array = temp_array + [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Delhi Daredevils':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Kings XI Punjab':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Kolkata Knight Riders':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Mumbai Indians':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Rajasthan Royals':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Royal Challengers Bangalore':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
        elif bowling_team == 'Sunrisers Hyderabad':
            temp_array = temp_array + [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

        overs = float(request.form['overs'])
        runs = int(request.form['runs'])
        wickets = int(request.form['wickets'])
        runs_in_prev_5 = int(request.form['runs_in_prev_5'])
        wickets_in_prev_5 = int(request.form['wickets_in_prev_5'])

        temp_array = temp_array + [overs, runs, wickets, runs_in_prev_5, wickets_in_prev_5]

        data = np.array([temp_array])
        my_prediction = int(model.predict(data)[0])

        return render_template('result.html', lower_limit = my_prediction-10, upper_limit = my_prediction+10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For more reference you can check below link:
https://ipl-scores-prediction.herokuapp.com/

Comment: it's  woking fine at given link address

Comment: Yeah...the issue is resolved..Thank you!